# Fetch some data from an api with React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, fetch

Im trying to fetch some data from an api but for some reason it's not working, i also tried with `Object.key`.

I have been doing api fetch a couple of times but i guess i don't understand this JSON format

Here is my code:

```
class CryptoNews extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            news: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?feeds=cryptocompare,cointelegraph,coindesk&extraParams=YourSite')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => this.setState({
    news: data
})
)}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.news.map((key) => (
            <div key={key.id}>
            <h2>{key.body}</h2>
        </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the `Data` property from the response object. 
So:

```
news: data.Data
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the Data array and set it to this.state.news.

The format of JSON message is like this.

```
{
 "Type":100,
 "Message":"News list successfully returned",
 "Promoted":[],
 "Data":[],
 "RateLimit":{},
 "HasWarning":false
}
```

your componentDidMount method should be like following

```
componentDidMount(){
 fetch('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/? 
 feeds=cryptocompare,cointelegraph,coindesk&extraParams=YourSite')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(data => this.setState({
    news: data.Data
 })
)}
```